# Is there special TexML syntax for key-value pairs

Tags: xml

Many TeX commands now work with key-value pairs, like this:

```
\mycommand{key1={myvalue},key2={othervalue}}
```

I can generate that sort of thing with TeXML (below), but it's ugly. Is there a better way?

```
<cmd name="mycommand">
  <parm>
    <TeXML escape="0">key1={</TeXML><xsl:value-of select="myselector1"/>
    <TeXML escape="0">},key2={</TeXML><xsl:value-of select="myselector2"/>
    <TeXML escape="0">}</TeXML>
    </parm>
</cmd>
```

Comment: This seems off-topic ... ?

Comment: Because it's about TeXML?

Comment: Is that TeX-based?

Comment: TeXML is a program that converts XML documents (in the TeXML format) into TeX files—more or less an intermediate format if you're generating TeX from XML. So it's not TeX but it's for TeX.